# Detecting a cycle given line segments

Tags: algorithm, graph, computational-geometry

I'm working on an implementation of the Slab Decomposition algorithm, for [point location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location) and I'm stuck in one of its final steps.
I have a list of vertexes and also a list of the vertexes' neighbors (for example, neighbor[0] has all vertexes that are connected to the vertex 0).
I can create the slabs described in the algorithm just fine, but after I detect between which line segments a point is, I don't know how to get the whole partition/cycle/face the point is in.

Basically, I have this

[image]

And this is what I want

[image]

I could just try to detect all cycles, in a brute force manner, but efficiency is important here. Any idea on how I should approach this problem?
All vertexes and line segments come from an input file, so I could order them in a certain way if it helps with the detection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the [planar straight-line graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Planar_straight-line_graph&redirect=no) as a [doubly connected edge list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list). The pertinent feature of the DCEL representation is that the base object be a half-edge (each segment gives rise to two oppositely oriented half-edges, with a tail and a head) with two operations:

```
DNext(HalfEdge e) - returns the next half-edge with the same head as e
                    in counterclockwise order around the head
Sym(HalfEdge e) - returns the oppositely oriented half-edge
                  corresponding to the same edge.
```

Then you can iterate through the half-edges comprising the face with `e = Sym(DNext(e))` until `e` returns to its starting value.

To compute the DCEL representation in the first place is a matter of sorting the half-edges by angle and then linking them together. There's a way to compare the angles of two half-edges using a 2x2 determinant calculation (avoiding an arctangent, if that's relevant to you).